# Why is my HTML Table resizing images when checkboxes are in my Table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is my code:

```html
<style>
  .autoResizeImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 10px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-79" name="79" /></td>
      <td style="padding: 10px;">
        <a href="giftcards/f-Anna.jpg"><img class="autoResizeImage" src="giftcards/f-Anna-thumb.jpg" /></a>
      </td>

      <td style="padding: 10px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-78" name="78" /></td>
      <td style="padding: 10px;">
        <a href="giftcards/fw2012.jpg"><img class="autoResizeImage" src="giftcards/fw2012-thumb.jpg" /></a>
      </td>

      <td style="padding: 10px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-77" name="77" /></td>
      <td style="padding: 10px;">
        <a href="giftcards/austin.jpg"><img class="autoResizeImage" src="giftcards/austin-thumb.jpg" /></a>
      </td>

      <td style="padding: 10px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-76" name="76" /></td>
      <td style="padding: 10px;">
        <a href="giftcards/jake.jpg"><img class="autoResizeImage" src="giftcards/jake-thumb.jpg" /></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I include the checkbox, the images incrementally get smaller:

[image]

When I remove the checkbox cells, the images look just fine:

[image]

If the images need to shrink, I'd like them to all shrink the same amount so their heights still match. How can I modify my CSS to fix this checkbox problem?

Comment: I don't see any issue. If you add the checkboxes, there is less space for the images. What is the expected result ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the max-width on the images?

Comment: Set the height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the table is being built, it doesn't know how much width to allocate for the checkbox cells, so as each checkbox cell is added, the available width left for the images becomes less and less. Assigning a static width for each checkbox cell will fix the issue:

```css
.autoResizeImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 10px; width: 20px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-79" name="79" /></td>
            <td style="padding: 10px;"><a href="giftcards/f-Anna.jpg"><img class="autoResizeImage" src="https://www.wehoville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/pygmy-goat.jpg" /></a></td>

            <td style="padding: 10px; width: 20px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-78" name="78" /></td>
            <td style="padding: 10px;"><a href="giftcards/fw2012.jpg"><img class="autoResizeImage" src="https://www.wehoville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/pygmy-goat.jpg" /></a></td>

            <td style="padding: 10px; width: 20px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-77" name="77" /></td>
            <td style="padding: 10px;"><a href="giftcards/austin.jpg"><img class="autoResizeImage" src="https://www.wehoville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/pygmy-goat.jpg" /></a></td>

            <td style="padding: 10px; width: 20px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-76" name="76" /></td>
            <td style="padding: 10px;"><a href="giftcards/jake.jpg"><img class="autoResizeImage" src="https://www.wehoville.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/pygmy-goat.jpg" /></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you examine the computed styles for each image in your code sample, you'll see that every image is set to a width of 100%, but "100%" becomes less and less as each `td` is added for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: Works great! Thanks.